# Test case specific log file using MSTest

Tags: c#, mstest

How to create test case specific log files using `MSTest` in c#?

I am using `TestContext.writeln()`. It seems fine, but when when running test cases  using:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "DataFile.xml", "Users", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```

everything is put into the same file.

In `TestNg` world I could use something like `Reporter.log()`, which was thread safe and create reports specific to each tests, even for tests with data provider.